# Remove rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe imported from CSV file. the output gives extra readings which are not required for my analysis. I want to drop all rows where say time is 15:30:00. It tried several methods not working.
i tried

```
df = df.query('Time' != 15:30:00)
df[(df.Time != 15:30:00)]
df = df[df.Time != 15:30:00]
df = df.drop(df.loc[df['Time']==15:30:00].index, inplace=True)
```

if someone has idea to do the same pls help

| Date_Time | High | Low | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-29 15:10:00 | 13646.1 | 13608.2 | 15:10:00 |
| 2021-01-29 15:15:00 | 13637.4 | 13596.8 | 15:15:00 |
| 2021-01-29 15:20:00 | 13639.0 | 13611.1 | 15:20:00 |
| 2021-01-29 15:25:00 | 13670.7 | 13623.8 | 15:25:00 |
| 2021-01-29 15:30:00 | 13663.0 | 13634.6 | 15:30:00 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your column "Date_Time" is datetime format. Then you need to do:

```
df = (df.set_index('Date_Time').between_time('15:30:00', '15:40:00')
          .reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns))
```

If you want only 15:30:00 you can set both limits to the same time

Answer (score 0):

The CSV you have shown in your table doesn't have a column named `Time`. Maybe that is your problem.

Given your CSV, this works:

```
df = df[df.Date_Time != '2021-01-29 15:30:00']
```

Comment: If you want to make datetime range queries, you can convert your first column to a Datetime type using `df['Date_Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']). Then, you can do things like df = df[df['Date_Time'] < datetime(2021, 01, 29)]